# total summed height of children elements are bigger than parent's height

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this experiment, the first child is only formed by padding, while the second child has to fill the remaining space of the parent container. To solve this, I tried using the `calc()` function, I subtracted `100vh`, which is the height of the parent element, by the total sum of padding-top and padding-bottom of the first element, which is `6rem`. The result I got was a height exceeding the height of the remaining space of the parent element, leaving an overflow.
[image]

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #dfdfdf;
}

.first-box {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3rem 0;
  background: firebrick;
  color: #dfdfdf;
  font: 1rem 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.second-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 6rem);
  background: purple;
  color: #dfdfdf;
  font: 1rem 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-box">This box has no height, only formed by padding</div>
  <div class="second-box">This box must fill the whole container with the remaining offset height of parent</div>
</div>
```

Should I use Javascript instead in a case like this? Because unlike in CSS, you can get the offset height of an element in Javascript whether it's formed by height or padding only.

Comment: you forgot lineheight. you need to subtract the lineheight of the font in .first-box

Answer (score 0):

You're already using flexbox so apply that to your container and let it deal with the height.

Your container will also need `flex-direction` to be set to column. Then remove the height property from your second box and add `flex: 1 1 auto;`.

Keep in mind that I haven't added any vendor prefixes in my example.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #dfdfdf;
}

.first-box {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3rem 0;
  background: firebrick;
  color: #dfdfdf;
  font: 1rem 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.second-box {
  width: 100%;
  background: purple;
  color: #dfdfdf;
  font: 1rem 'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-box">This box has no height, only formed by padding</div>
  <div class="second-box">This box must fill the whole container with the remaining offset height of parent</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is flexbox the only solution? What if the browser I'm using doesn't support flexbox?

Comment: There's more than one solution however your example code contained flexbox so my answer is based on the assumption you'd already considered browser support and determined that flexbox was acceptable. Personally, I believe we're at the point where flexbox is fine to use but check caniuse.com for full details on support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Okay. Thanks again :)